# How can I convert strings to an html color code hash?

Tags: php, html, hash, colors

I'd like to represent strings as arbitrary html colors.

Example:

"blah blah" = #FFCC00
"foo foo 2" = #565656

It doesn't matter what the actual color code is, so long as it's a valid hexadecimal HTML color code and the whole spectrum is fairly well represented.

I guess the first step would be to do an MD5 on the string and then somehow convert that to hexadecimal color code?

**Update:** Usage example is to generate a visual report of file requests on a server. The colors don't have to look pretty, it's more so a human brain can detect patterns, etc in the data more readily.

Comment: Do you want to map a string to a 6 digit hex code ?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would be using these strings? Why don't you just put the color codes in php variables?

Comment: going with codaddict's thinking: hash it and take the first 6 bytes?

Comment: Usage example is to generate a visual report of file requests on a server. The colors don't have to look pretty, it's more so a human brain can detect patterns, etc in the data more readily.

Comment: So based on the number of file requests, you want to give the filename a different color? In php?

Comment: I think it can be done way more intelligent way than just random numbers.

Comment: If hashing is to be used. Why not use CRC32 that created a 32-bit hash which you can represent directly as a ARGB color model.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers, this seems to do a competent job:

```
function stringToColorCode($str) {
  $code = dechex(crc32($str));
  $code = substr($code, 0, 6);
  return $code;
}

$str = 'test123';
print '<span style="background-color:#'.stringToColorCode($str).'">'.$str.'</span>';
```

Comment: exactly the solution I was looking for.

Comment: A similar concept but different hash was provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704220/change-random-strings-into-colours-consistently For me, it seemed to provide a more varied color combination. Perhaps the distribution of hashes is different for md5() vs dechex(crc32())

Comment: Why not simply bin2hex() with substr()?

Answer (score 27):

Almost always, just using random colours will

1. look bad
2. conflict with the background

I would recommend creating a (longish) list of colours that work well together and with your background - then just hash the string and modulus (%) with your number of colours to get an index into the table.

```
public function colorFromString($string)
{
  $colors = [
    '#0074D9',
    '#7FDBFF',
    '#39CCCC',
    // this list should be as long as practical to avoid duplicates
  ];

  // generate a partial hash of the string (a full hash is too long for the % operator)
  $hash = substr(sha1($string), 0, 10);

  // determine the color index
  $colorIndex = hexdec($hash) % count($colors);

  return $colors[$colorIndex];
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. You should include a function for it to be complete.

Answer (score 21):

I agree with sje397 above that completely random colours could end up looking nasty. Rather than make a long list of nice-looking colours, I would suggest choosing a constant saturation+luminescence value, and varying the hue based on the content. To get an RGB colour from an HSL colour, you may use something similar to what's described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB .

Here's an example (try it in <s>http://codepad.viper-7.com</s> something that works, such as https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/ZXBMZWYJFO):

```
<?php

function hsl2rgb($H, $S, $V) {
    $H *= 6;
    $h = intval($H);
    $H -= $h;
    $V *= 255;
    $m = $V*(1 - $S);
    $x = $V*(1 - $S*(1-$H));
    $y = $V*(1 - $S*$H);
    $a = [[$V, $x, $m], [$y, $V, $m],
          [$m, $V, $x], [$m, $y, $V],
          [$x, $m, $V], [$V, $m, $y]][$h];
    return sprintf("#%02X%02X%02X", $a[0], $a[1], $a[2]);
}

function hue($tstr) {
    return unpack('L', hash('adler32', $tstr, true))[1];
}

$phrase = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
$words = [];
foreach (explode(' ', $phrase) as $word)
    $words[hue($word)] = $word;
ksort($words);
foreach ($words as $h => $word) {
    $col = hsl2rgb($h/0xFFFFFFFF, 0.4, 1);
    printf('<span style="color:%s">%s</span> ', $col, $word);
}
?>
```

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' after $a because of old PHP version.

Comment: this will fix the parsing issue: $a = [[$V, $x, $m], [$y, $V, $m], [$m, $V, $x], [$m, $y, $V], [$x, $m, $V], [$V, $m, $y]]; $a = $a[$h];

Comment: btw - i found that this will make good text colors: function colorFromText($text) { return hsl2rgb(hueFromText($text)/0xFFFFFFFF, 0.8, 0.6); }

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. Unfortunately, in my case the colours it generates are very similar. For some ~20 2-digit integers, I'm getting colours that are [all between green and yellow](https://i.imgur.com/GhNYh6Y.png). If I hash `$tstr` with `sha1()` first, I indeed [get more colours](https://i.imgur.com/y7kDseA.png), but some of them still look like duplicates. Is there a better way to convert arbitrary text to hue, or with my ~20 values am I asking for too much?

Answer (score 14):

One liner:

```
substr(md5($string), 0, 6);
```