# Random Colors populated for each box

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC 4 Project and my view renders a table with multiple rows and columns based on data passed my model. I want to populate each box with different color. It needs to be random, I do not want to keep an array of colors as number of fields in table may vary.

Comment: what I have read of developers doing in this case is generate a MD5  based on some data and then translate that to a color code using an algorithm. hope this helps...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263140/random-color-generation-using-php

Comment: I found the link to the stack overflow I read it on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724111/how-can-i-convert-strings-to-an-html-color-code-hash